# BACKPACK Laravel manage extra columns in pivot table in a many-to-many relationship using Backpack CRUD

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm using backpack for laravel and I'm trying to add/update some extra columns in a pivot table used in a many-to-many relationship.

Summarizing the context: I have a model **Task**, another model **Machine** and this intermediate pivot table **machine_task** containing the many-to-many relation between Task and Machine

In this machine_task there are **machine_id**, **task_id** and then boolean columns **m** (for 'monthly'), **q** (for 'quarterly'), **b** (for 'biannual') and **y** (for 'yearly').

This is what I have

In my **Models/Task.php** I've defined the m-2-m relationship

```
   public function machines()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Machine')->withPivot('m','q','b','y');
    }
```

In **/app/Http/Controllers/Admin/TaskCrudController.php** I have the fields, the most relevant one being this

```
       $this->crud->addField([   // n-n relationship
           'label' => "Machines", // Table column heading
           'type' => "select2_from_ajax_multiple_custom", // a customized field type modifying the standard select2_from_ajax_multiple type
           'name' => 'machines', // the column that contains the ID of that connected entity
           'entity' => 'machines', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
           'attribute' => "name", // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
           'model' => "App\Models\Machine", // foreign key model
           'data_source' => url("api/machines"), // url to controller search function (with /{id} should return model)
           'placeholder' => "Select machine(s)", 
           'minimum_input_length' => 0, 
           'pivot' => true, 

           'dependencies' => ['building_id'], // this "Machines" field depends on another previous field value
           ]);
```

This works perfectly: When I create or update a Task, the AJAX call is made returning the right results, values are correctly added into the select2 input, and the pivot table **machine_task**  is correctly filled and updated with **task_id** and **machine_id** when I click on the Save and back button.

But how to insert into the pivot table the extra values **m**,**q**,**b**,**y** alongside **task_id** and **machine_id**?

At the end of **TaskCrudController.php** I have

```
 public function store(StoreRequest $request)
    {
        // your additional operations before save here
        // What I should do here to get the pivot values into the request??????????????
        $redirect_location = parent::storeCrud($request);
        // your additional operations after save here
        // use $this->data['entry'] or $this->crud->entry
        return $redirect_location;
    }

    public function update(UpdateRequest $request)
    {
        // your additional operations before save here
        // What I should do here to get the pivot values into the request??????????????
        $redirect_location = parent::updateCrud($request);     
        // your additional operations after save here
        // use $this->data['entry'] or $this->crud->entry
        return $redirect_location;
    }
```

In my modified version of **select2_from_ajax_multiple** I have added some rows with checkboxes for each of the options selected. Let's see in a screenshot for better understanding

[select2_from_ajax_multiple_custom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vo9w.png)

In **/vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/fields/select2_from_ajax_multiple_custom.blade.php** I initialize the values like this, and then I use jquery to update the rows synced with the select2 control, but I don't know how to associate the m,q,b,y checkboxes with each of the select2 selected options and to pass them to the request.

```
    @if ($old_value)
            @foreach ($old_value as $item)
                @if (!is_object($item))
                    @php
                        $item = $connected_entity->find($item);
                    @endphp
                @endif
                <div id="div{{ $item->getKey() }}">
                <span> {{ $item->getKey() }} {{ $item->{$field['attribute']} }} -- </span>
                Monthly <input type="checkbox" id="m{{ $item->getKey() }}" name="m{{ $item->getKey() }}" value="1" @php if ($item->pivot['m'] == "1") echo "checked"; @endphp > 
                Quarterly <input type="checkbox" id="q{{ $item->getKey() }}" name="q{{ $item->getKey() }}" value="1" @php if ($item->pivot['q'] == "1") echo "checked"; @endphp> 
                Biannual <input type="checkbox" id="b{{ $item->getKey() }}" name="b{{ $item->getKey() }}" value="1" @php if ($item->pivot['b'] == "1") echo "checked"; @endphp> 
                Yearly <input type="checkbox" id="y{{ $item->getKey() }}" name="y{{ $item->getKey() }}"value="1" @php if ($item->pivot['y'] == "1") echo "checked"; @endphp> <br/>
                @php
                @endphp
                </div>
            @endforeach
        @endif
```

Thank you very much in advance for your time and I hope you can help me! Kinda stuck with this!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've been able to solve it, so I'll post the solution as it may be useful for others.

What I did,

In my **TaskCrudController.php** I added the underlying Task model

```
// add this to the use statements 
use App\Models\Task;
```

then, also in **TaskCrudController.php** I made this

```
// Notice: You need to add this to "create" function as well, I'm just writing here the update function to keep it short.
 public function update(UpdateRequest $request)
    {
$redirect_location = parent::updateCrud($request);
foreach ($request->machines as $machine) {
            $set= array('m'=>'0','t'=> '0', 's' => '0', 'a' => '0');
            if (isset($request['m'])) in_array ($machine, $request['m']) ? $set['m'] = '1' :  $set['m'] = '0';
            if (isset($request['t'])) in_array ($machine, $request['t']) ? $set['q'] = '1' :  $set['q'] = '0';
            if (isset($request['s'])) in_array ($machine, $request['s']) ? $set['b'] = '1' :  $set['b'] = '0';
            if (isset($request['a'])) in_array ($machine, $request['a']) ? $set['y'] = '1' :  $set['y'] = '0';

            Task::find($request->id)->machines()->syncWithoutDetaching([$machine => $set]);
return $redirect_location;
        }

// Code explanation:
// what we are doing basically here is to grab the $request data
// For example: In the $request we receive m[3] b[1,3] y[1] arrays
// meaning that for our task:
// Machine 1 has no monthly, no quarterly but biannual and yearly checkboxes checked
// Machine 3 has monthly, no quarterly, biannual and no yearly checkboxes checked
// with the loop above, we cast that incoming data into this structure
// $set would contain after the loop:
// '1' => ['m' => '0', 'q'=> '0', 'b' => '1', 'y' => '1']
// '3' => ['m' => '1', 'q'=> '0', 'b' => '1', 'y' => '0']

// with that, we updated the intermediate table using syncWithoutDetaching
```

Now let's see **select2_from_ajax_multiple_custom.blade.php** although I'm not posting all code (the rest is the same as select2_from_ajax_multiple standard field)

```
<div @include('crud::inc.field_wrapper_attributes') >
   <label>{!! $field['label'] !!}</label>
   @include('crud::inc.field_translatable_icon')
   <select
       name="{{ $field['name'] }}[]"
       style="width: 100%"
       id="select2_ajax_multiple_custom_{{ $field['name'] }}"
       @include('crud::inc.field_attributes', ['default_class' =>  'form-control'])
       multiple>

       @if ($old_value)
           @foreach ($old_value as $item)
               @if (!is_object($item))
                   @php
                       $item = $connected_entity->find($item);
                   @endphp
               @endif
               <option value="{{ $item->getKey() }}" selected>
                   {{ $item->{$field['attribute']} }}
               </option>
           @endforeach
       @endif
   </select>
// What I added is:
   <div id="freq">
   @if ($old_value)
           @foreach ($old_value as $item)
               @if (!is_object($item))
                   @php
                       $item = $connected_entity->find($item);
                   @endphp
               @endif
               <div id="div{{ $item->getKey() }}">
               <span>{{ $item->{$field['attribute']} }} -- </span>
               Monthly <input type="checkbox" id="m{{ $item->getKey() }}" name="m[]" value="{{ $item->getKey() }}" @php if ($item->pivot['m'] == "1") echo "checked"; @endphp > 
               Quarterly <input type="checkbox" id="q{{ $item->getKey() }}" name="q[]" value="{{ $item->getKey() }}" @php if ($item->pivot['q'] == "1") echo "checked"; @endphp> 
               Biannual <input type="checkbox" id="b{{ $item->getKey() }}" name="b[]" value="{{ $item->getKey() }}" @php if ($item->pivot['b'] == "1") echo "checked"; @endphp> 
               Yearly <input type="checkbox" id="y{{ $item->getKey() }}" name="y[]"value="{{ $item->getKey() }}" @php if ($item->pivot['y'] == "1") echo "checked"; @endphp> <br/>

               </div>
           @endforeach
       @endif
   </div>


// js code to add or remove rows containing the checkboxes (This needs to be put inside <script> tags obviously)    $("#select2_ajax_multiple_custom_machines").on("select2:select", function(e) {
// add checkbox row
           htmlRow = "<div id=\"div"+e.params.data.id+"\">"+"<span> "+e.params.data.text+"-- </span>"+" Monthly <input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"m"+e.params.data.id+"\" name=\"m[]\" value=\""+e.params.data.id+"\">";
           htmlRow += " Quarterly <input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"q"+e.params.data.id+"\" name=\"q[]\" value=\""+e.params.data.id+"\">";
           htmlRow += " Biannual <input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"b"+e.params.data.id+"\" name=\"b[]\" value=\""+e.params.data.id+"\">";
           htmlRow += " Yearly <input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"y"+e.params.data.id+"\" name=\"y[]\" value=\""+e.params.data.id+"\"><br/>";
           htmlRow += "</div>";
           $("#freq").append(htmlRow);  
       });

$("#select2_ajax_multiple_custom_machines").on("select2:unselect", function(e) {
// remove checkbox row
           $("#div"+e.params.data.id).remove(); 
});
```

And that's all, folks.
Hope it helps.