# Save custom data into pivot table using select2_multiselect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, crud, laravel-backpack

I currently have a `users` table and a `books` table, with a pivot table `user_book` which has `user_id`, `book_id` as well as `book_tag` (this can be 'H' for happy, 'S' for sad or 'A' for angry)

Against the advice of the backpack team, we are looking to have three multiselect options, which will popoulate with the 3 different types of book tags, i.e. Happy books, Sad books, and Angry books.

I currently have the following definition inside the `initFields` function:

```php
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

class UserCrudController extends UserCrudController
{
    // ....

    protected function initFields()
    {
        // crud fields here
        $this->crud->addField([
            'label' => "Happy books",
            'type' => 'select2_multiple',
            'name' => 'books_h',
            'entity' => 'books',
            'model' => "App\Models\Book",
            'pivot' => true,
        ]);
    }
}
```

This however, does not seem to save. Any assistance is greatly appreciated

Comment: Check this one, seems to have a similar problem as you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56495180/backpack-laravel-manage-extra-columns-in-pivot-table-in-a-many-to-many-relations

Comment: @workservice, it appears they're using a custom select... Also, I have to mention I just started backpack

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure the the relation `books_h` is defined correctly in your entity as `belongsToMany` relationship based on laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

like so

```
public function books_h(): 
 \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class, 'user_book', 'user_id', 'book_id', 'id', 'id')->withPivot('book_tag');
    }
```

then you need to overwrite both `create` and `update` methods to update the request for these fields to transfer it to look like so

```
[
    1 => ['book_tag' => 'H'],
    2 => ['book_tag' => 'H'],
]
```

before calling `$response = $this->traitUpdate();`
refer to this link for more info https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-operation-update#override-the-update-method

but I would recommend to use the correct way backpack team mentions https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-fields#save-additional-data-to-pivot-table even if you want to have it as 3 separate fields you can define the subfields as hidden with the value you want